# Facing Issue with Azure function binding types

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

In our project previously Azure Function was  using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and runtime version is ~1.
While deploying the same code to new app service and by default the runtime version comes with 3.0.15417.0 and .netcore3.0.
While publishing we are facing the below issue and if I click yes and continue app gets published. But app in portal wont work so reverted the change to version ~3.
We are using blob triggers and the send grid.[image].
And could see The binding type(s) 'blob rigger, blob' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.

[image]

```
host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extension Bundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this solve your problem? If you have any other problems, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct to set `Runtime version` to `v1`. Your problem is that `Connection` is not configured in `Application settings`:

For example:

[image]

You need to configure `conn` in `Application settings`:

[image]